# python argparse : use two groups of required arguments

Tags: python, argparse

I have a python program that can take arguments in two modes :

EITHER (a) OR (b AND c AND d).

I've looked at `add_mutually_exclusive_group` but it does not allow to have one subgroup with a list of required arguments

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you thought of checking the arguments yourself? Is (a) defined? or is both (b, c, d) defined?

Comment: Right, exclusive group uses a simple xor logic.  `argparse` does not provide any more complex grouping or logic.  `a is None` (the default default) is a good test for the occurrence (or not) of the `a` argument.  `subparsers` is the only other grouping tool, which may be overkill in this case.

Comment: I don't think a subparser here would be overkill at all. Provide two subcommands, with `foo` requiring exactly one argument and `bar` exactly three.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the second mode require 3 arguments, like this:

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument(
    '--mode1',
    metavar='A',
    )
group.add_argument(
    '--mode2',
    nargs=3,
    metavar=('B', 'C', 'D'),
    )
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Example output:

```
$ ./test.py -h
usage: test.py [-h] (--mode1 A | --mode2 B C D)

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  --mode1 A
  --mode2 B C D
$
$ # Valid arguments
$ ./test.py --mode1 foo
Namespace(mode1='foo', mode2=None)
$ ./test.py --mode2 foo bar baz
Namespace(mode1=None, mode2=['foo', 'bar', 'baz'])
$
$ # Invalid arguments
$ ./test.py --mode1 foo bar
usage: test.py [-h] (--mode1 A | --mode2 B C D)
test.py: error: unrecognized arguments: bar
$ ./test.py --mode2 foo bar
usage: test.py [-h] (--mode1 A | --mode2 B C D)
test.py: error: argument --mode2: expected 3 argument(s)
$ ./test.py
usage: test.py [-h] (--mode1 A | --mode2 B C D)
test.py: error: one of the arguments --mode1 --mode2 is required
```